# How can i remove the missing subpackage error in a phpcs ruleset?

Tags: phpcodesniffer

I want to remove this because i dont need it on my project.

```
 <rule ref="Squiz.Commenting.FileComment">
    <properties>
        <property name="subpackage" value="false"/>
    </properties>
 </rule>
```

See you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to exclude that specific error message in your ruleset.xml file is to use:

```
<exclude name="Squiz.Commenting.FileComment.MissingSubpackageTag" />
```

Use the `-s` command line argument to determine the code for a specific error message. You'll see something like this:

```
Missing @subpackage tag in file comment
(Squiz.Commenting.FileComment.MissingSubpackageTag)
```

If you want to exclude the whole sniff, you'd instead use:

```
<exclude name="Squiz.Commenting.FileComment" />
```

There are a lot of other things you can do in a ruleset file. See the docs for more examples: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-ruleset.xml